# How to create a new Context from scratch in NodeJS

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am working on a bot-based application that sends proactive messages to the team.

My query is, **How can we create a new Context to work with to be able to send a proactive message after server restart**.

So, that means we are getting context only after receiving messages from Teams. which results in we can’t send messages after the server is restarted.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you're losing the context, it sounds like you're only storing them in memory - this is not correct, otherwise you will experience exactly that. These context details need to be saved on your server side into a proper permanent data storage mechanism (e.g. dDatabase or blob storage or whatever you choose, but something permanent, not just memory).

Separately though, it's worth noting that you don't -actually- need to store the 'context' - that's just one approach, that's used a lot in the Microsoft samples. I find it easier to store just a subset of required data, being the ServiceUrl and the Conversation Id. Please see here for a sample: https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/tree/main/samples/bot-proactive-messaging . I put both a dotnet as well as a node.js version in the sample, and there are some links at the bottom of the page to read more about the topic. Here is also a link to a video session where I talk more about the concept: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mM7-fYdcJhw&t=1398s.